# Nokogiri 1.5.2 not installing on Ubuntu 11.10

Tags: ruby, rubygems, nokogiri, ubuntu-11.10

Real quick, I am aware of a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003523/error-installing-nokogiri-1-5-0-with-rails-3-1-0-and-ubuntu). However, following the top rated answer does not work. I've already restarted my system and the terminal, but to no avail.

For some reason, Nokogiri does not recognize that I have `libxslt1-dev` installed, though I explicitly installed it, both with `sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev` and `sudo apt-get install libxslt1-dev`.

Here's the output; am I missing anything else?

```
$ gem install nokogiri -v '1.5.2'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

~/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/ruby extconf.rb
extconf.rb:10: Use RbConfig instead of obsolete and deprecated Config.
checking for libxml/parser.h... yes
checking for libxslt/xslt.h... yes
checking for libexslt/exslt.h... yes
checking for iconv_open() in iconv.h... no
checking for iconv_open() in -liconv... yes
checking for xmlParseDoc() in -lxml2... yes
checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... no
-----
libxslt is missing.  please visit 
http://nokogiri.org/tutorials/installing_nokogiri.html for help
with installing dependencies.
-----
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
    List of options

Gem files will remain installed in ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2 for inspection.
Results logged to ~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

**EDIT:** Upon closer inspection, I realize that the installer recognizes that I have `libxslt1-dev` installed, but it's failing one of the tests. Did I do something wrong with the installation?

**EDIT 2:** I am trying to install `capybara` with `bundle install`, and among its several dependencies, `nokogiri` and `selenium-webdriver` cannot find `libxslt`, and therefore I cannot use `capybara`.

**EDIT 3:** Here's the error message from the `mkmf.log` file; let me know if you need the rest of it.

```
--------------------

find_library: checking for xsltParseStylesheetDoc() in -lxslt... -------------------- no

"gcc -o conftest -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I${HOME}/.rvm/usr/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC  -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline conftest.c  -L. -L${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -Wl,-R${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-R/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -Wl,-R${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L${HOME}/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R${HOME}/.rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lxml2 -liconv  -Wl,-R -Wl,${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -lruby -lxslt -lxml2 -liconv  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc "
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:5:53: error: ‘xsltParseStylesheetDoc’ undeclared (first use in this function)
conftest.c:5:53: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
conftest.c:5:28: warning: variable ‘p’ set but not used [-Wunused-but-set-variable]
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: /*top*/
4: int main() {return 0;}
5: int t() { void ((*volatile p)()); p = (void ((*)()))xsltParseStylesheetDoc; return 0; }
/* end */

"gcc -o conftest -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/x86_64-linux -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1/ruby/backward -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/ruby-1.9.1 -I. -I/opt/local/include/libxml2 -I/usr/local/include/libxml2 -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include/libxml2 -I/opt/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/include -I/usr/include -I/usr/include/libxml2 -I${HOME}/.rvm/usr/include     -O3 -ggdb -Wextra -Wno-unused-parameter -Wno-parentheses -Wno-long-long -Wno-missing-field-initializers -Wpointer-arith -Wwrite-strings -Wdeclaration-after-statement -Wimplicit-function-declaration  -fPIC  -g -DXP_UNIX -O3 -Wall -Wcast-qual -Wwrite-strings -Wconversion -Wmissing-noreturn -Winline conftest.c  -L. -L${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -Wl,-R${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L/opt/local/lib -Wl,-R/opt/local/lib -L/usr/local/lib -Wl,-R/usr/local/lib -L${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -Wl,-R${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L/usr/lib -Wl,-R/usr/lib -L${HOME}/.rvm/usr/lib -Wl,-R${HOME}/.rvm/usr/lib -L.  -rdynamic -Wl,-export-dynamic    -lxml2 -liconv  -Wl,-R -Wl,${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -L${HOME}/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p125/lib -lruby -lxslt -lxml2 -liconv  -lpthread -lrt -ldl -lcrypt -lm   -lc "
conftest.c: In function ‘t’:
conftest.c:5:1: warning: implicit declaration of function ‘xsltParseStylesheetDoc’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlMutexUnlock@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashScan@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathWrapNodeSet@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStringText@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferClose@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDoc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewParserCtxt@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcasecmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStringTextNoenc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDocCopyNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlUTF8Strpos@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDoc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetMerge@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlUnlinkNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewComment@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGenericError@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeAddContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictOwns@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewTextLen@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeGetBase@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrlen@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHasNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeNodeList@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocPI@LIBXML2_2.6.15'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPtrEval@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsBaseCharGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferCCat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewMutex@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSetNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeMutex@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlParseURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetDtdAttrDesc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSaveUri@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashLookup3@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBuildURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDocSetRootElement@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathConvertString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrncat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterVariableLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlParserGetDirectory@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSetProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashUpdateEntry@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlURIEscapeStr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetAddUnique@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetLineNo@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsBlankNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathStringFunction@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlModuleOpen@LIBXML2_2.6.17'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrdup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferCat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStringCurrentChar@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashAddEntry3@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewNs@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCharInRange@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlDocContentDumpFormatOutput@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCompiledEvalToBoolean@LIBXML2_2.6.27'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewNodeSet@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictQLookup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlDocContentDumpOutput@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrEqual@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetCharEncodingName@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewChild@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcat@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictReference@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrchr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashCreate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsDigitGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFunctionLookupNS@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCastNodeToString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCtxtUseOptions@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathContextSetCache@LIBXML2_2.6.25'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeDtd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferFlush@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocText@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferCreateFd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeObject@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNsLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNumberFunction@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNextAncestor@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathEvalExpression@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetCreate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrncmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrndup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferWriteQuotedString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlValidateQName@LIBXML2_2.5.4'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictCreateSub@LIBXML2_2.6.5'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrcmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashRemoveEntry@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashAddEntry2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterFuncNS@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashRemoveEntry2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeGetSpacePreserve@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPtrNewContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewBoolean@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashScanFull@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlNewDoc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewCDataBlock@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrPrintf@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCastToString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCheckFilename@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCompiledEval@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathEvalPredicate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCompile@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlValidateNCName@LIBXML2_2.5.4'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCopyCharMultiByte@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeGetContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocNodeEatName@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `valuePop@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlNewDocNoDtD@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathInit@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashUpdateEntry3@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetDocEntity@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `inputPush@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferCreateFile@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeCompExpr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlUTF8Strloc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathIsNodeType@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlParseDocument@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSearchNs@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewText@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlModuleClose@LIBXML2_2.6.17'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlMalloc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferAdd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashAddEntry@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterFuncLookup@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGenericErrorContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathOrderDocElems@LIBXML2_2.5.6'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictCreate@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathIsNaN@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDocGetRootElement@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeNodeSet@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeDumpOutput@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlModuleSymbol@LIBXML2_2.6.17'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAddID@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictLookup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCmpNodes@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathDebugDumpObject@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCreateURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlDictFree@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAddPrevSibling@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewCString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSearchNsByHref@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathErr@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlRealloc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathRegisterFunc@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrstr@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXIncludeProcessFlags@LIBXML2_2.6.3'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeSetContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferCreate@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathConvertNumber@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsCombiningGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlBufferContent@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferWriteString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlOutputBufferCreateFilename@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAddChild@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `valuePush@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeURI@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewParserContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetID@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNodeListGetString@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathEval@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFindCharEncodingHandler@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsID@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashUpdateEntry2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlLoadExternalEntity@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlAllocOutputBuffer@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlMutexLock@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetIntSubset@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlStrncasecmp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathStringEvalNumber@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNextPrecedingSibling@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `htmlSetMetaEncoding@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathObjectCopy@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeRefTable@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlSplitQName2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNodeSetAdd@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathCtxtCompile@LIBXML2_2.6.5'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlIsExtenderGroup@LIBXML2_2.6.0'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlGetNsList@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathIsInf@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewNsProp@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeParserCtxt@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathNewValueTree@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlFreeIDTable@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlCreateIntSubset@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlXPathFreeParserContext@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlNewDocNode@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
/usr/lib/libxslt.so: undefined reference to `xmlHashLookup2@LIBXML2_2.4.30'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
checked program was:
/* begin */
1: #include "ruby.h"
2: 
3: /*top*/
4: int main() {return 0;}
5: int t() { xsltParseStylesheetDoc(); return 0; }
/* end */

--------------------
```

Comment: Is there a 32/64 bit mismatch? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3496857/function-xsltparsestylesheetdoc-not-found-in-libxml2-so  Or maybe this one has an answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1225703/cant-build-gem-native-extension-build-fails-can-you-see-why

Comment: @John I don't think so; `apt-get` has always given me the correct package wrt to 32/64 bits. (I'm on `x86_64`, and the package is an `amd64` package.) I reinstalled it just to be sure, and I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: What about running the `apt-get` mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8003523/error-installing-nokogiri-1-5-0-with-rails-3-1-0-and-ubuntu ?

Comment: @Deradon Yes, that's the one I linked to at the beginning of my post. All the libraries specified by `rvm requirements` have been installed.

Comment: So you _might_ need to reinstall your rvm ruby. `rvm reinstall 1.9.3`
It's working like a charm on my Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: @Deradon Just tried reinstalling Ruby and restarted. Still displays the same error though.

Comment: Can you find and post the `mkmf.log` file generated when you tried to build this gem? There are usually some hints contained in there.

Comment: @mlc What `mkmf.log` file? I'm not using capistrano. I do, however, see a `gem_make.out` file, but it's identical to what I pasted here.

Comment: @Edwin try looking in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125@rails3tutorial2ndEd/gems/nokogiri-1.5.2`

Comment: @mlc I didn't know that even existed. Quick grep showed me where, though. Since it's so long, I just posted the error message.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you have more than one copy of `libxml2` (and possibly `libxslt`) installed, and they are confusing each other. Try searching for and removing any extra copies of these libraries (and their include files) from your system.

Comment: You're right; it looks like I had two versions. For reasons beyond my comprehension, reinstalling `libxml2-dev` solved the problem. Not sure what the system was doing trying to find `2.4.30` when it's currently `2.7.8` via `apt-get`.

Comment: How would you find another copy of libxml2 in your app?

Answer (score 0):

Some ideas to try:

- try installing 1.5.0. If that fails at least you know it's your
  problem not nokogiri.
- try --with-xslt-dir --with-xslt-include and --with-xslt-lib options. Maybe you have an old libxslt earlier in your path

Comment: Not sure what you mean by the first point, but I know I have no earlier versions of `libxslt` when I run `whereis libxslt` and `locate libxslt`.