# Why doesn't nokogiri install?

Tags: ruby, rubygems, ubuntu-12.04, nokogiri, rbenv

I'm having a devil of a time installing Nokogiri on Ubuntu 12.04. I use rbenv.

```
    $ gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
    ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES)
        Permission denied - /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/.autotest

    $ sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
    ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        nokogiri requires Ruby version >= 1.9.2.

    $ rbenv sudo gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
    Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
    ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
        ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/bin/ruby extconf.rb

    Gem files will remain installed in /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1 for inspection.
    Results logged to /home/deploy/.rbenv/versions/2.0.0-p353/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/nokogiri-1.6.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out

    $ ruby -v
    ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

    $ sudo ruby -v
    ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [x86_64-linux]

    $ rbenv sudo ruby -v 
    ruby 2.0.0p353 (2013-11-22 revision 43784) [x86_64-linux]

    $ echo $PATH
    /home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/home/deploy/.rbenv/shims:/home/deploy/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games
```

It seems like I need some way of having `sudo ruby -v` give me `2.0.0`. What am I missing?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10148704/nokogiri-1-5-2-not-installing-on-ubuntu-11-10) may help

Comment: Try `sudo -E ruby -v` to copy your environment variables into the `sudo` session. `rvmsudo` might also be worth a shot?

Comment: Your third attempt looks correct. What is the result in the log file? (it may be a different problem)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You shouldn't need `sudo` when you do `gem install` with rbenv. Unfortunately, the ownership is usually not correct for the .rbenv directory on a new install.

Do this first to set your permissions correctly:

```
sudo chown -R $USER "$HOME/.rbenv"
```

Then go ahead and just run the install again:

```
gem install nokogiri -v '1.6.1'
```

It should work without `sudo`.

Answer (score 1):

This works fine, but make sure to restart your terminal window after running sudo chown.

```
sudo chown -R $USER "$HOME/.rbenv" 

# close terminal, then run the gem install

gem install nokogiri
```