# rbenv - any reasons why x86_64-darwin-13 is installed with root perms?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rbenv

full path: /Users/meeeee/.rbenv/versions/2.1.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-darwin-13

Prevented me from installing sqlite had to change owner. Just curious why it was root and wanna make sure it doesn't cause issues later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having a lot of problems installing rubygems because of the permissions on this directory. So, I also am hoping for an explanation as to why it is rooted as well. However, my reputation is not high enough to upvote or comment, so I'm going to tell you what I did!

I spent a lot of time making sure my PATH was set up correctly, reading past issues on rbenv's github, and then I found this: [Why doesn't nokogiri install?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21371459/why-doesnt-nokogiri-install-ubuntu-12-04-rbenv?rq=1)

The answer indicates that rbenv usually doesn't set the correct permissions on a new install. Weird. But I thought I would just take their word for it and try it out.

I changed the ownership of x86_64-darwin-13 to my user and now my gems install without needing sudo.

```
$ sudo chown -r USER:GROUP /Path/To/x86_64-darwin-13
```

Comment: Yeah thts pretty much what I did. Was just curious :-/ ah well. Thanks anyho.